# is this a good way to align a struct to be used in arrays?

Tags: c++, performance, optimization, memory-management, alignment

i wrote this code to optimize the struct to be aligned for array usage :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
struct  Foo  {          
     int z;        
     char c;
} __attribute__((packed));
struct FooForArray
{
     Foo f;
     char aligner[sizeof(int)-sizeof(Foo)%sizeof(int)];   // fill the missing bytes with this dump array for aligment  
};              
int main()
{
    std::cout<<"sizeof AlignedFoo = "<<sizeof(FooForArray)<<std::endl;  
    std::cout<<"sizeof Foo = "<<sizeof(Foo)<<std::endl;    
      system("pause");  
}
```

output :

```
sizeof AlignedFoo = 8
sizeof Foo = 5
Press any key to continue...
```

I think that most compilers will do that by default , but im doing this for learining , is it a good approach ?

Comment: I don't follow. Why do you need this complexity? What alignment are you trying to achieve? And why?

Comment: I coding a game engine for embedded systems and im trying to improve performance

Comment: An alignment of 6 seems very unusual.

Comment: @DhiaHassen _"and im trying to improve performance"_ You may probably achieve the opposite using unaligned memory then.

Comment: you are right , the acctule code is `char aligner[sizeof(int)-sizeof(Foo)%sizeof(int)];` i edited it when posting by mistake , now it is aligning to 8

Comment: so now is it a good approach  ? and thanks